# Material Design Bootstrap is not working in AngularJS single page application

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, bootstrap-material-design

I am working on MEAN Stack application. I want to use Bootstrap Material Design CSS styles to my ***single page application*** but **routing** is not working when using **mdb.min.css** .what is the solution to avoid this problem.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Testing Application</title>
    <!-- STYLESHEETS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-view></div>
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/routingCtrl.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginCtrl.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

if i add **mdb.min.css** the routing page is not visible in ng-view.but if i remove **mdb.min.css** the page is visible without styling

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CDN by adding it to the head tags of your root index.html of your angular app like this.

```html
<head>
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If it doesn't work please make your issue more elaborate.